# Turn off mvc request logging in asp.net core 2.2 with serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I am using `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` to logs in file.

Here is my `appsettings.json` file:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "None",
      "Microsoft": "None"
    }
  },
  "LoggingFile": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "pathFormat": "C:/logs/APILogs-{Date}.log",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "None",
      "Microsoft": "None"
    }
  }
```

My Startup.cs code:

```
public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app, 
            IHostingEnvironment env, 
            IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // Removed other codes
            loggerFactory.AddFile(Configuration.GetSection("LoggingFile"));
        }
```

But It still log mvc request info such as below:

> 2019-09-21T13:28:59.6337460+05:30 80000019-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
>   [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:53534/api/values 
>   (ca22a1cb)
>
> 2019-09-21T13:28:59.8309629+05:30 80000019-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
>   [INF] Request finished in 202.16ms 200  (791a596a)
>
> 2019-09-21T13:29:00.1500727+05:30 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
>   [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:53534/favicon.ico
>   (ca22a1cb)
>
> 2019-09-21T13:29:00.2020227+05:30 8000001a-0004-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb
>   [INF] Request finished in 73.5631ms 200  (791a596a)

I don't to log these. It should only log when I want to log, such as in my contrller

```
_logger.LogInformation("Hello Info");
_logger.LogError("Hello error");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add following line of code to constructor of startup

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile("C:/logs/APILogs-{Date}.log")
            .CreateLogger();
```

And Then In confgure method, Add below line.

```
loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

For more info: [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#instructions)

You can remove configuration from appsettings.